# Evaluation of Extract and use the result in a Sum

Tags: evaluation, summation, scoping

I am experiencing a problem in the evaluation of a sum. I hope that someone can help me, I am not an expert Mathematica programmer. I'm posting just the portion of code that gives problems, I know that this is silly but it is embedded in a more complicated function.

```
Module[{r = Extract[{0, 0, x, y, 0}, 3], 
        inf = Extract[{0, 0, x, y, 0}, 5], 
        sp = x + y}, 
        Sum[t^sp, {r, inf, Infinity}, 
          Assumptions -> {t < 1 && t > 0}]
]
```

I need to select the index of the Sum from a list of symbols, for example x or y. While the evaluation of the lower and upper bounds of the Sum is done as expected, I cannot see the way of selecting the index and I obtain that the sum does not converge:

```
Sum[t^(x + y), {r$42458, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {t < 1 && t > 0}]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to replace the iteration variable in sum with some other selected variable.

The reason your code doesn't work is that, in `Sum` the iteration variable is localised by making use of `Block`. You can use [With](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to replace all occurrences of a symbol inside an expression with another value (even inside held expressions) So

```
With[{r = Extract[{0, 0, x, y, 0}, 3], 
    inf = Extract[{0, 0, x, y, 0}, 5], 
    sp = x + y}, 
    Sum[t^sp, {r, inf, Infinity}, 
      Assumptions -> {t < 1 && t > 0}]]
```

will give what you expect.

> $\frac{t^y}{(1 - t)}$